# Numba RuntimeError only when directly running on databricks notebook

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to understand the source of runtime error when I run the following python function in a databricks notebook vs importing and invoking it from a module

**Running directly on databricks notebook**

```
def test_numba_func():
    from numba import jit

    @jit(cache=True)  
    def test():
        return .5 ** 2 / 4.0

    print(test())
```

invoking this function does not work

`test_numba_func()`

**RuntimeError: cannot cache function 'test_numba_func..test': no locator available for file ''**

However if I create a module say databricks_test.py with the same function, then the following import works without any issues.

**Module import**

```
import databricks_test
databricks_test.test_numba_func()
```

Databricks notebook
[image: Databricks notebook screenshot]

I am able to run in directly in Colab though.

[image]

I think this is due to some rights issue. How can I fix my code to make it work against databricks?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that notebooks on Databricks aren't the real files - they are kept in memory when you're using them, and persisted to something like Database on the fly.  This is different from the using the module that is real file, or Google notebooks where they are also files on the disk.

Theoretically you can try to set environment variable `NUMBA_CACHE_DIR` to something like `/tmp/cache` ([docs](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/developer/caching.html#the-implementation)), but I'm not sure that it will work. Also, it will work only until cluster is terminated.

Comment: I was aware of the NUMBA_CACHE_DIR approach, but unfortunately this and .numba_config.yaml (https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/envvars.html)  are not working out. I have tried them on notebook as well as DBConnect.  In the actual implementation I am working on, the numba jit decorated functions are inside an installed package (real files), but I still face the same issue.  [Edit - clarified response]